# Python file .exe just appear in a moment and close immediately after that

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame. I have made a code about the game similar to dinosaur game when the internet is interupt. But when I convert from .py to .exe it just open in a moment and close immediately although main script runs fine. The command I've been using was pyinstaller file.py --onefile which make a executable that keeps closing immediately when i run it. I have checked wheather there is a error but it doesn't( i dont you any image.png outside)

```
import pygame
import time
import random
import sys

pygame.init()

white = (255,255,255)
yellow = (255,255,102)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (235, 64, 52)
width = 1000
height = 600

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
score_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monospace', 35)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
def message(msg, color):
    mesg = font_style.render(msg, True, color)
    screen.blit(mesg, (round(width/3), round(height/3)))
bush_speed = 1


def your_score(score1):
    value = score_font.render("Your Score: " + str(score1), True, yellow)
    screen.blit(value, [0, 0])


game_over = False
def collision(player_pos,bush_pos):
    p_x = player_pos[0]
    p_y = player_pos[1] 
    b_x = bush_pos[0] 
    b_y = bush_pos[1] 
    if (b_x >= p_x and b_x < p_x + 50 ) or (b_x == p_x) or (p_x >= b_x and p_x < b_x + 50) :
        if (b_y >= p_y and b_y < p_y + 100) or (b_y == p_y) :
            return True

    return False

def bush(bush_height,bush_pos):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,red, [bush_pos[0],bush_pos[1],50,bush_height])

def speed(bush_speed,score1):
    if score1 < 3:
        bush_speed = 50
    elif score1 < 20:
        bush_speed = 4 
    elif score1 < 30:
        bush_speed = 5
    else:
        bush_speed = 15

def game_loop():
    game_close = False
    player_pos = [200,500]
    player_jump =[0,0]
    player_height = 100
    player_size = 50
    score1 = 0
    game_over = False
    bush_size = 50
    bush_height = (round(random.randint(50,100)/10) *10)
    bush_pos = [width - bush_size, height - bush_height]

    while not game_over:
        
        while game_close:
            screen.fill(white)
            message("You Lost! Press C-Play Again or Q-Quit", red)
            pygame.display.update()

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_c:
                        game_loop()
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        game_over = True
                        game_close = False

        screen.fill(black)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                game_over = True
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if player_pos[0] > 0:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player_pos[0] -= 50
                if player_pos[0] < width - player_size:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player_pos[0] +=50
                if player_pos[1] == height -100:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        player_pos[1]   -=200
                        player_jump[0] = 1
        if player_pos[1] < height  - player_height :        
            player_pos[1] += player_jump[0]
        
        bush_pos[0] -= bush_speed*2


        clock.tick(200)
        if bush_pos[0] < 0 :
            bush_height = (round(random.randint(50,100)/10) *10)
            bush_pos = [width - bush_size, height - bush_height]
            score1 +=1
        speed(bush_speed,score1)

        if collision(player_pos,bush_pos):
            game_close = True
            

        bush(bush_height,bush_pos)
        your_score(score1)
        


        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (player_pos[0],player_pos[1],player_size,player_height))
        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.display.flip()

game_loop()
```

sorry if my english is bad and my knowledge of code is too limited

Comment: as a general recommendation, on Windows and elsewhere, it can be useful to run on the command line to see what errors and complaints get thrown out.  a misbehaving GUI app often dies without telling you much, but its command line might.  so, instead of double-clicking on `c:\foo.exe` in Explorer or running by menu, open a DOS/Powershell and type `c:\foo.exe` and hit return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts are often the issue here, same goes for audio files. Try replacing:

```
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 30)
```

with

```
font_style = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 30)
```

Arial is pretty much always a "safe bet" in these cases. Also before converting with pyinstaller change your file name to `main.py`. Also do not forget to update `pygame` to `2.0.0.dev6` or newer.
It should work now.

Comment: Pygame 2.0.0 was released on October 28th.  https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases/tag/2.0.0 - it's not clear on the PyGame website if this is considered a "stable" release, but there is no "dev~" suffix. The OP should use that, or the latest marked stable 1.9.6.

Comment: @Kingsley I was not aware of this release. `1.9.6` and Python `3.8 ` had some compatibility issued (especially with audio files) when converting to `.exe` with pyinstaller.  `2.0.0.dev6` resolved those problems. I should have mentioned that in my answer. But I agree with you that stable releases should be used, and in that case I strongly recommend `1.9.6` with python `3.7.x` (preferably the latest one).

Comment: okkkk it world very softly tkssss youuuu so much @kaktus_car. Btw , may i ask you that why my original font it didn't work? (tkss yoou again :>)

Comment: Someone correct me if I am wrong, either its pyinstaller omits some files from the distribution which are available otherwise, or there is problem with paths. Also you can always use `pygame.font.Font("myfont.ttf", 30)` (Notice: not `SysFont`) and include this file to your `dist` folder, or anywhere else as long as you update the path of the font in `pygame.font.Font`. This way you can add any font to your project.